# Liquid CSS layout issues

Tags: css, html, liquid-layout

Alright I have a CSS liquid div based layout for my personal web site.  The address is 
http://danberinger.com/preview.html

The problem is the I do not want the footer section to act as if it were displayed inline, because right now when the window is stretched beyond the pixel width needed for the intro_container, it moves the footer div to the right of it.  I would like this footer to stay put at the bottom of the page rather than moving up and to the right when space allows for it.

Thanks for any help you can offer. I have loved this forum so far, very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
}
```

This will ensure it is always pushed down below all other floated content. This seems to provide the effect you are asking for.

Comment: the first answered worked but it did not center the footer like it needed to be, plus its more of a css patched up version of what I want.  This is the right way to do it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

here is css fix for it

```
#footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work I believe because the messagebox and the picture are both floated inside their container, therefore the when I use that CSS fix it places the footer on top of the floated items..

Comment: scratch that, you were right, it just acted funny in dreamweaver, thankyou

Comment: This will do horrible horrible things if the viewport is smaller than the height of the website. The footer will be stuck to the bottom of the viewport and not the bottom of the actual page.

Comment: Yes, I should of thought of clearing the float first. I guess since they were nested within another containing div and then centered from there I didn't think it would be an issue.  I am no CSS expert but I like to think I know a good bit. Thank you very much for the correct, right way to do it!